# Newly opened window is not getting preferences from parent window in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating an application which is having digestive authentication process. From one window, when clicking on particular link we will get a new window which will have digestive authentication. I'm using Firefox browser for my automation. When I do it from system profile, it's working fine, but when I use custom profile from selenium, it's not automatically authenticated. I suspect that preferences from parent window is not shared with new window. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the window is definitely opening in the profile you need it to.
If it isn't, a good idea is to go through and check that the webdriver settings are connected to the correct profile.

If that is all correct, ensure the settings within your custom Firefox profile are the exact same as the ones within the system profile.

You can check the profile running in the terminal:

```
firefox -P
```

This should open the profile manager.
Hope I've helped :)